# Continuous Error in argument "x" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, function, if-statement, missing-data

I am trying to build a function that takes a numeric vector of homework scores (of length n), and an optional logical argument drop, to compute a single homework value. If drop = TRUE, the lowest HW score must be dropped.

### step1 function to get average

```
    get_average <- function(x,na.rm=TRUE) { 
   if(na.rm==TRUE){
         x = remove_missing(x)}
       total <- 0
       for (n in 1:length(x)) {
total= total  + x[n]

    }
   return(total/length(x))
  }
```

### put it all together

```
    score_homework <- function(x,drop=TRUE)  
     {
     if(drop==TRUE)
       x = drop_lowest(x)
    {get_average(x)}}
```

However I keep getting the error Error in score_homework() : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: So? How exactly are you calling the score_homework function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you want, but here goes.

First generate some dummy data:

```r
# Set seed
set.seed(1234)

# Generate dummy homework data with <NA> values
homework <- c(rep(NA, 20), rnorm(n = 100, mean = 50, sd = 10))

# Have a quick look
hist(homework)
```

[image]

Then we write the function:

```r
# Make function
homework_func <- function(data, drop = TRUE) {
    # Remove NA
    data <- data[!is.na(data)]

    # Calculate the average depending on whether 'drop' is T or F
    if(drop == TRUE) {
        data <- data[data > min(data)]
        mean(data)
    } else {
        mean(data)
    }
} 

# Use function with 'drop = TRUE'
homework_func(data = homework, drop = TRUE)
#> [1] 48.65349

# Use function with 'drop = FALSE'
homework_func(data = homework, drop = FALSE)
#> [1] 48.43238
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to eliminate the lowest missing score that's less complicated than the version in the original post. I sort the scores in descending order in case the there is a tie for the lowest score. In that case, we should only remove one instance of the lowest score.  Also, you're really better off using R's `mean()` function than writing your own.

```
scores <- c(78,93,61,NA,61,83,92,95,NA,100)

removeMinScore <- function(x) {
     x <- x[order(-x)] # order descending
     x <- x[!is.na(x)] # remove NAs
     x[1:length(x)-1] # return all but lowest score, removes only 1 tied value
}
```

That said, if you must write your own version of `mean()`, here is a simpler approach that takes advantage of existing R functions.

**TIP:** Since `is.na()` returns a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values, you can sum these to count the number of non-missing values in a vector.

```
mymean <- function(x) {sum(x, na.rm=TRUE) / sum(!is.na(x))}
```

The results look like this.

[image]

The modified version of `score_homework()` would be:

```
score_homework <- function(x,drop=TRUE){
    if(drop == TRUE) return mean(removeMinScore(x),na.rm=TRUE)
    else mean(x,na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

The results from testing the function are as follows.

[image]